# How to organize two UIViews within one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I use Xcode 6.1.1 and objective-c.
I have a Viewcontroller with two UIviews.
I am trying to switch between the two views in the code and that is working alright.

My problem is when I go to the Storyboard there are two UIviews laying over each other. In short it looks very messy ;). What are possible things I can do to keep it organized?

Is it for example possible to add a uiview directly to the storyboard and load it in the UIviewcontroller when needed?

Or make two UIviewcontrollers and load the uiview from the other Uiviewcontroller?

Comment: you can create different UIView in xib file and load it using name like  UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nameOfXib"
                                                           owner:self
                                                         options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: @Jageen , Thanks good idea. have not used a .xib in a while :) thanks to storyboard. Would that be a efficient option?

Comment: Yes i used in my project to but, did not create more xibs it will increase size of your application, but for two views, i guess it is ok.

Comment: @Jageen , Yes that is right. It is indeed for just 2 uiviews.

Comment: I am going off for while, post me if you get any problem I will post sample link.